# Get element in array (json format)

Tags: javascript, json

how can i get the first "id_miembro" for example of this:

```
{"actividades":[{"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"AC-04","id_actividad":"D-01","id_seccion":"S-03"},{"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"AC-02","id_actividad":"D-01","id_seccion":"S-01"}]}
```

I've tried with other ways but nothing, thanks.

Comment: What language are you trying to access it in?

Comment: What ways have you tried? And what is not working? What languages are you trying to parse this JSON with?

Comment: i've ready fix my question, sorry

Comment: You have not changed anything, please tell us what language you are using or we cannot help you

Comment: check it out, i've two instead one

Comment: Ok i didn't see that, but still - what language?..

Comment: in javascript or jquery will work for me, sorry i'm new in this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing a JSON string in javascript can be done with [JSON.parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). For your JSON you can do this to get the `id_miembro` of the first item in the list.

```
var json = '{"actividades":[{"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"AC-04","id_actividad":"D-01","id_seccion":"S-03"},{"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"AC-02","id_actividad":"D-01","id_seccion":"S-01"}]}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var actividades = obj.actividades;
var first = actividades[0];
var id_miembro = first.id_miembro;
```

I broke it down into seperate variables so it's easier to follow which line does what.

If your data is alread a javascript object you can skip the first two lines and just do this

```
var obj = {"actividades":[{"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"AC-04","id_actividad":"D-01","id_seccion":"S-03"},{"id_miembro":"V-005","id_dpto":"AC-02","id_actividad":"D-01","id_seccion":"S-01"}]};

var actividades = obj.actividades;
var first = actividades[0];
var id_miembro = first.id_miembro;
```